# Print only lines that are completely numeric

Tags: text-processing, awk, numeric-data

I'd like to filter through a text file and *only* print the lines where each column is a valid floating point number. For example:

```
3 6 2 -4.2 21.2 
3 x 4.2 21.2 
3 2 2.2.2
```

Only the first line would pass as `x`, nor `2.2.2` are valid floats. I can write a python script that simply `.splits()` and runs a `try/except` block over each part, but this is slow for larger files. The input file has an unknown variable length number of columns and no scientific notation will be used. Is there an `awk` solution?

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '
    # skip any obvious stuff
    /[^0-9. -]/ {next}
    {
        # test each field for a number
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
            if ($i + 0 != $i)
                next
        print
    }
'
```

This will break for valid numbers in scientific notation: `1.2e1 == 12`

Comment: One can easily add `e` in the regular expression `[^0-9. -e]`. The test will then only fail when there are only `e`'s in the line.

Comment: Be careful with bracket expressions: `[0-9. -e]` will match **any** character from space (ascii 32) to `e` (ascii 101). You want `[^0-9. e-]`: to match a literal hyphen, it needs to be either the first or the last character, otherwise it defines a range of chars. (https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Range-Operator.html#Range-Operator)

Answer (score 2):

based on the conditions you state regex might be a possibility. I was able to get the following GNU awk script to work on RHEL.

```
 awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i !~ /^[-]?[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?$/) break;if (i == NF)print($0)}}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$ cat data.txt 
3 6 2 -4.2 21.2 
3 x 4.2 21.2 
3 2 2.2.2

$ awk '/^\s*(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?\s+)+\s*$/ { print }' < data.txt 
3 6 2 -4.2 21.2
```

Comment: PS: you asked for awk. Should be using grep instead...